# What do "receive" and "send" mean in the context of the "on_message" event?

Tags: python, discord.py

In the discord.py [Quickstart](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot) tutorial the `on_message` function is described as:

> 3. [...] the `on_message()` event is called when the bot has **received** a message.
> 4. Since the `on_message()` event triggers for every message **received**, [...]

which is how I would understand this function intuitively.

However, it refers to the [API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message), which says:

> `discord.on_message(message)`
>
> Called when a Message is created and **sent**.
>
> [...]
>
> Your bot's own messages and private messages are **sent** through this
> event. [...]

To me this sounds like the exact opposite. Why do "receive" and "send" seemingly mean the same in this context? How to interpret this contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they're saying the same thing, just from different perspectives.

A message that the bot receives has to have first been sent by some other component of Discord.

It's like saying that your phone rings when it receives a call or when someone calls you.